# Smartcontract lottery project - brownie compile generates Connection Error : 404

Tags: brownie

When I am trying to brownie compile "smartcontract-lottery" I get a connection error -> Something like this :  : ***ConnectionError: Status 404 when getting package versions from Github: 'Not Found'***

Comment: Can you provide a link to the repository?

Comment: This might be better suited on the repo you're working with. Could you post all associated code you're working on?

Comment: Thanks Patrick and Ismael for your response. I think I found the issue : In the brownie config section : I changed the version of the chainlink brownie contract / openzepplin contract to 0.2.2 and 4.3.2 ; the changes are reflected in the remappings section as well ...